# Are there any scripts that lets the user press a "copy" button to copy the URL from an embed text field (similar to Github's)?

Tags: flash

Is there a script similar to the image below that lets the user press a copy button to copy text to their clipboards (instead of right-clicking to copy)?

[alt text http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/7593/rtomaykosrdiscountatmas.png](http://img709.imageshack.us/img709/7593/rtomaykosrdiscountatmas.png)

Here's the URL where I got that image: http://github.com/rtomayko/rdiscount

Any ideas where I can find a script to do implement that functionality?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640227/copying-textarea-text-regardless-of-browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub uses [Clippy](http://github.com/mojombo/clippy).

[Zero Clipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/) is another solution as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried Googling but didn't know what terms to use. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

```
textField.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler );

private function clickHandler( e : MouseEvent ) : void {
    System.setClipboard( e.target.text );
}
```